# Drools: Recommended way to include multiple drl files, for breaking up business logic

Tags: drools, rules, rule-engine

I have an application I am trying to experiment with. The business rules I am trying to create are all related but it makes sense for me to group the logic by drl file. For example, I want to put information about customers in the customer.drl file. I want to put logic about the categories of product in the productCategory.drl file and purchases.drl. Finally, I'd like to have a fourth file summarizing my findings for a report.drl

I don't want to create entirely separate modules. I just want to split out the logic so that I can easily maintain the logic in the code. In effect, I'd like something like this:

```
 src/main/resources/rules
                    customers.drl
                    purchases.drl
                    productCategory.drl
                    reports.drl
```

I want to be able to share the logic between the facts in a single KieSession, utilizing all the drl files. First, I want to insert customer facts, group them by demographics, then insert their purchase information and products purchased and categorize them. Finally, I want to aggegrate that data in a report by inserting the previously gathered facts to generate data from the reports.drl

Is the configuration, I'm showing a feasible way of doing it.  I'm of course assuming that the KiesSession will pick all the drl files in the rules package if I use a classpath container.
Is this the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation, I can group related rules under the same package. It is one of the options available. So for my use case this works. According to the documentation, I can create a kmodule.xml, and indicate the package, use a classpath container and load the KieSession. If I use a default kmodule definition with no KieBase defined, it will use a default KieBase and load all the resources in the src/main/resources and its other subfolders and this works!